# FIrebase using ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, angularfire2

I am using ionic2 with firebase.

Here is my app component.

```
 import { Component, ViewChild,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav,NavController,Platform ,AlertController,MenuController,App,IonicApp} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Splashscreen ,Network,Toast,LocalNotifications} from 'ionic-native';
import { ComplaintsPage } from '../pages/complaints/complaints';
import { MycomplaintsPage } from '../pages/mycomplaints/mycomplaints';
import { ChatlistPage } from '../pages/chatlist/chatlist';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { IndexPage } from '../pages/index/index';
import { Authservice } from '../providers/authservice';
import { NeighboursPage } from '../pages/neighbours/neighbours';
import { NotificationsPage } from '../pages/notifications/notifications';
import { UpdateprofilePage } from '../pages/updateprofile/updateprofile';
import { DirectoryPage } from '../pages/directory/directory';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { SettingsPage } from '../pages/settings/settings';
import { EventPage } from '../pages/event/event';
import { PropertyPage } from '../pages/property/property';
import { AlbumPage } from '../pages/album/album';
import { VisitorsPage } from '../pages/visitors/visitors';
import { ExpectedvisitorsPage } from '../pages/expectedvisitors/expectedvisitors';
import { CircularPage } from '../pages/circular/circular';
import { DashboardPage } from '../pages/dashboard/dashboard';
import { AlarmPage } from '../pages/alarm/alarm';
import { AlarmdetailsPage } from '../pages/alarmdetails/alarmdetails';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
declare var navigator: any;
declare var Connection: any;
declare var window: any;
declare var FCMPlugin;
declare var Media:any;
export interface PageInterface {
  title: string;
  component: any;
  logsOut?: boolean;
  icon?:string;

} 
interface /*PhoneGapNavigator extends*/ Navigator {
  app: any;
}


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {
  audio;
  public app: App;
  currentuser;
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav1: Nav;
  auth:any;
  menu;
  nav:NavController;
  rootPage:any = LoginPage;
  loginPages:PageInterface[]=[
      { title: 'Login', component: LoginPage  }
  ];
  showRoot = false;
  ApartID;
  USERID;
  EMERGENCY;
  logo;
  Apartmentname;
  logoutpages :PageInterface[] = [
      { title: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardPage, icon:'dashboard.svg'},
      { title:'Emergency',component:AlarmPage,icon:'alarm.svg'},
      { title:'Albums',component:AlbumPage, icon:'album.svg' },
      { title: 'Repairs', component: MycomplaintsPage, icon:'complaints.svg'},
      { title:'My Neighbours',component:NeighboursPage, icon:'neighbours.svg'},
      { title:'Notifications',component:NotificationsPage, icon:'notification.svg'},
      { title:'Directory',component:TabsPage, icon:'directory.svg'},
      { title:'Chats',component:ChatlistPage, icon:'chat.svg'},
      { title:'Community News',component:CircularPage, icon:'circullar.svg'},
      { title:'Amneties Booking',component:EventPage, icon:'booking.svg'},      
      { title:'Visitors',component:VisitorsPage, icon:'visitor.svg'},
      { title:'Property',component:PropertyPage, icon:'buy_sell.svg'},
      { title:'Settings',component:SettingsPage, icon:'settings.svg'},
      { title: 'LogOut',component:LoginPage,logsOut:true, icon:'logout.svg'}

    ];
  managementuser:PageInterface[] = [
      { title: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardPage, icon:'dashboard.svg'},
      { title:'Emergency',component:AlarmPage,icon:'alarm.svg'},
      { title:'Albums',component:AlbumPage, icon:'album.svg' },
      { title: 'Repairs', component: MycomplaintsPage, icon:'complaints.svg'},
      { title:'My Neighbours',component:NeighboursPage, icon:'neighbours.svg'},
      { title:'Notifications',component:NotificationsPage, icon:'notification.svg'},
      { title:'Directory',component:TabsPage, icon:'directory.svg'},
      { title:'Chats',component:ChatlistPage, icon:'chat.svg'},
      { title:'Community News',component:CircularPage, icon:'circullar.svg'},
      { title:'Amneties Booking',component:EventPage, icon:'booking.svg'},      
      { title:'Visitors',component:VisitorsPage, icon:'visitor.svg'},
      { title:'Property',component:PropertyPage, icon:'buy_sell.svg'},
      { title:'Settings',component:SettingsPage, icon:'settings.svg'},
      { title: 'LogOut',component:LoginPage,logsOut:true, icon:'logout.svg'}

    ];
 userrole:PageInterface[] = [
   { title:'Property',component:PropertyPage, icon:'buy_sell.svg'},
   { title:'Settings',component:SettingsPage, icon:'settings.svg'},
   { title: 'LogOut',component:LoginPage,logsOut:true, icon:'logout.svg'}
 ]   

  constructor(public af:AngularFire,public fb:FormBuilder,private Status:StatusBar,public appCtrl: App,public menu1: MenuController,public alertCtrl:AlertController,public platform: Platform,public authservice:Authservice) {

    this.auth=localStorage.getItem("email");
    var roleid=localStorage.getItem('Roleid');
    console.log("Auth"+this.auth);

    if(this.auth != undefined && this.auth != null) 
    {
      this.authservice.getcurrentuserID().first().subscribe(
      data=>{
        var apartid=data[0].APART_ID;
        this.authservice.getallapartments(apartid).subscribe(
          data=>{
            this.logo=data[0].APART_LOGO;
            this.Apartmentname=data[0].APART_NAME;
            console.log(this.logo);
          })
      })
    }

    if(this.auth != undefined && this.auth != null)
    {
      if(roleid === '3' || roleid === '4')
        {
          this.rootPage = DashboardPage;
        }
        if(roleid === '2' || roleid === '5')
        {
          this.rootPage = DashboardPage;
        }
        if(roleid === '6')
        {
          this.rootPage = PropertyPage;
        }
    }


    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

     var url='https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/Loud-Ringtone-11-Emergency-Alert.mp3?alt=media&token=7d67b437-e96b-484e-bd97-008106a06dcb';
     this.audio = new Media(url,

        // success callback

        function () { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success"); },

        // error callback

        function (err) { console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err); },

        function(statusCallback){console.log("Status"+statusCallback)}


    ); 
   })


    this.showRoot = true;

    this.initializeApp();






  }

  initializeApp() {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

       this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {
            console.log('[INFO] App paused');
            console.log("backround");
            localStorage.setItem("apprunning",'paused');
        });

        this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {
            console.log('[INFO] App resumed');
            console.log("foreground");
            localStorage.setItem("apprunning",'resumed')
        });

      let self = this;
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
     // this.Status.styleDefault();
      this.Status.backgroundColorByHexString("#0e5591");
      this.hideSplashScreen();

      this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {

        //window.plugins.toast.show("Press again to exit", "short",'center',2000);
        if (this.nav1.canGoBack()) {
          console.log('nav can go back');
          this.getActivePage();
          var page1=localStorage.getItem('email');
          var page2=localStorage.getItem('page');
          if( page2 != 'LoginPage')
          {
            console.log("page2 :"+page2);
            console.log("goto back success");
            this.nav1.pop();
          }
          if(page2 == 'LoginPage')
          {
            console.log("page2 :"+page2);
            console.log("goto back failed then exit to app");
            this.exit();
          }

        } 
         else{
           console.log("exit");
            this.exit();
        }
       })

      //Push Notifications

      if(typeof(FCMPlugin) !== "undefined")
      {
        FCMPlugin.getToken(function(t){
          console.log("Use this token for sending device specific messages\nToken: " + t);
        }, function(e){
          console.log("Uh-Oh!\n"+e);
        });

         FCMPlugin.onNotification(function(d){
          if(d.wasTapped){  
            console.log(d);
            var nav=self.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(NotificationsPage);
          } else {
            // Foreground receival, update UI or what have you...

             console.log("Push Notification", d);
             window.plugins.toast.show("You have new notifications", "short",'bottom',1500);
             console.log("you have new notifications");
          }
        }, function(msg){
          console.log("msg");
          console.log(msg);
          // No problemo, registered callback
        }, function(err){
          console.log("Arf, no good mate... " + err);
       });

      }

      if(Network.type === Connection.NONE)
      {
      console.log("success");
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: "Internet Connection",
      subTitle:"Please Check Your Network connection",
      buttons: [
      {
      text: 'Ok',
      handler: () => {
      this.platform.exitApp();
      }
      }
      ]
      });
      alert.present();

     }
    });

  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
   // this.authservice.getLoggedInUser();
    this.nav1.setRoot(page.component);
    if (page.logsOut === true) {
      this.authservice.logout();
      localStorage.clear();
    }
  }

  isUserLoggedIn():boolean {
      let user = this.authservice.getcurrentuser();
      this.currentuser=localStorage.getItem('Roleid');
      // console.log(this.currentuser);
      // console.log(typeof(this.currentuser));
      return user !== null;
 }

  check():any
  {
    this.authservice.checkRole().subscribe(data=>{
      this.currentuser=data[0].ROLE_ID;
      console.log(this.currentuser)
      console.log(typeof(this.currentuser));
    })
  }


  exit(){
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Confirm',
        message: 'Do you want to exit?',
        buttons: [{
          text: "Ok",
          handler: () => { this.exitApp() }
        }, {
          text: "Cancel",
          role: 'cancel'
        }]
      })
      alert.present();
  }

  //App exit

  exitApp(){
    this.platform.exitApp();
  }

  //Splashscreen hide

  hideSplashScreen() {
    if(navigator && navigator.splashscreen) {
      setTimeout(()=> {
      navigator.splashscreen.hide();
      }, 500);
    }
  }

  getActivePage() {
    //var val= this.nav1.getActive().name;
    var val=this.nav1.getPrevious().name;
    console.log("val");
    console.log(val);
    localStorage.setItem('page',val);

  }

  Backroundnotifications()
  {
      //Get Current UserID

      var roleid1=localStorage.getItem('Roleid');
      this.authservice.getcurrentuserID().subscribe(
        data=>{
          console.log(data);
          this.ApartID=data[0].APART_ID;
          this.USERID=data[0].USER_ID;
          this.EMERGENCY=[];
           if(roleid1 === '2' || roleid1 === '5')
        {
          this.authservice.GetEmergencytype(this.ApartID).subscribe(d=>{
              var EM=d;
              this.EMERGENCY=EM.filter(a=>a.FROM.toString() != this.USERID.toString());
              console.log("EMERGENCY");
              var emergencyval=this.EMERGENCY.filter(d=>d.STATUS == 'ON');
              console.log("TYPE");
              console.log(emergencyval);

                  //  if(emergencyval.length != 0)
                  //  {
                  //    if(emergencyval[0].STATUS === "ON")
                  //   {
                  //    var e=emergencyval[0];
                  //    var key=emergencyval[0].$key;
                  //    // this.schedule(e);
                  //    //  LocalNotifications.on("click", (notification, state) => {
                  //    //        this.audio.stop();
                  //    //        this.nav1.setRoot(AlarmdetailsPage);
                  //    //    });
                  //   }
                  // }
              })
            }
        })
  }

  Foregroundnotifications()
  {
      //Get Current UserID
      this.audio="";
      var roleid1=localStorage.getItem('Roleid');
      this.authservice.getcurrentuserID().subscribe(
        data=>{
          console.log(data);
          this.ApartID=data[0].APART_ID;
          this.USERID=data[0].USER_ID;
          this.EMERGENCY=[];
           if(roleid1 === '2' || roleid1 === '5')
        {
          this.authservice.GetEmergencytype(this.ApartID).subscribe(d=>{
              var EM=d;
              this.EMERGENCY=EM.filter(a=>a.FROM.toString() != this.USERID.toString());
              console.log("EMERGENCY");
              var emergencyval=this.EMERGENCY.filter(d=>d.STATUS == 'ON');
              console.log("TYPE");
              console.log(emergencyval);

                   if(emergencyval.length != 0)
                   {
                     if(emergencyval[0].STATUS === "ON")
                    {
                      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
                      window.plugins.toast.show("Emergency notifications", "short",'bottom',3000);
                     });
                    }
                  }
              })
            }
        })
  }

   schedule(a)
  {
      console.log("receive Notification")
      var val=a;
      var t:any=a.MSG;
      var time:any=a.SEND_TIME;
       LocalNotifications.schedule({
            title: "Smart Premises",
            text: t,
            at: time,
            sound:this.playSelectedTrack(),
      });



  } 

  playSelectedTrack():any{
    console.log("audio play");
     this.audio.play();
  } 

}
```

Here is my  dashboard.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams ,Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { LocalNotifications,Toast} from 'ionic-native';
import { FirebaseAuth, AuthProviders, AuthMethods} from 'angularfire2';
import { Authservice } from '../../providers/authservice';
import { AlbumPage } from '../../pages/album/album';
import { MycomplaintsPage } from '../../pages/mycomplaints/mycomplaints';
import { NeighboursPage } from '../../pages/neighbours/neighbours';
import { NotificationsPage } from '../../pages/notifications/notifications';
import { ChatlistPage } from '../../pages/chatlist/chatlist';
import { TabsPage } from '../../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { CircularPage } from '../../pages/circular/circular';
import { EventPage } from '../../pages/event/event';
import { SettingsPage } from '../../pages/settings/settings';
import { VisitorsPage } from '../../pages/visitors/visitors';
import { AlarmPage } from '../../pages/alarm/alarm';
import { AlarmdetailsPage } from '.././alarmdetails/alarmdetails';
import { PropertyPage } from '../../pages/property/property';

import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
declare var Media:any;
declare var window: any;
/*
  Generated class for the Dashboard page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
})
export class DashboardPage {
 EMERGENCY=[];
 ApartID;
 USERID;
 audio;
 audioplaying;


  constructor(public af:AngularFire,public fb:FormBuilder,public platform: Platform,public authservice:Authservice,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public auth: FirebaseAuth) {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

     var url='https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/Loud-Ringtone-11-Emergency-Alert.mp3?alt=media&token=7d67b437-e96b-484e-bd97-008106a06dcb';
     this.audio = new Media(url,

        // success callback

        function () { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success"); },

        // error callback

        function (err) { console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err); },

        function(statusCallback){console.log("Status"+statusCallback)
         this.audioplaying = statusCallback;
         localStorage.setItem("audioplaying",this.audioplaying);
      }

    ); 

  })

  }



  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DashboardPage');
    this.Backroundnotifications();
  }

  albums() {
    this.navCtrl.push(AlbumPage);
  }
  complaints() {
    this.navCtrl.push(MycomplaintsPage);
  }
  myNeighbours() {
    this.navCtrl.push(NeighboursPage);
  }
  notification() {
    this.navCtrl.push(NotificationsPage);
  }
  chats() {
    this.navCtrl.push(ChatlistPage);
  }
  directory() {
    this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);  
  }
  circular() {
    this.navCtrl.push(CircularPage);
  }
  eventbooking() {
    this.navCtrl.push(EventPage);
  }
  settings() {
    this.navCtrl.push(SettingsPage);
  }
  visitors() {
    this.navCtrl.push(VisitorsPage);
  }
  propertyPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(PropertyPage); 
  }
  alarmPage() {
    this.navCtrl.push(AlarmPage);
  }

  //receive notifications

  schedule(a)
  {
      console.log("receive Notification")
      var val=a;
      var t:any=a.MSG;
      var time:any=a.SEND_TIME;
       LocalNotifications.schedule({
            title: "Smart Premises",
            text: t,
            at: time,
            sound:this.playSelectedTrack(),
      });

  } 

  playSelectedTrack():any{
    console.log("audio play");
     this.audio.play();

  } 

  Backroundnotifications()
  {
      //Get Current UserID

      var roleid1=localStorage.getItem('Roleid');
      this.authservice.getcurrentuserID().subscribe(
        data=>{
          console.log(data);
          this.ApartID=data[0].APART_ID;
          this.USERID=data[0].USER_ID;

           if(roleid1 === '2' || roleid1 === '5')
        {
          this.authservice.GetEmergencytype(this.ApartID).subscribe(d=>{
              var EM=d;
              this.EMERGENCY=EM.filter(a=>a.FROM.toString() != this.USERID.toString());
              console.log("this.EMERGENCY");
              console.log(this.EMERGENCY);
              if(this.EMERGENCY[0].STATUS == 'ON')
              {
                console.log("this");
                console.log(this.EMERGENCY[0]);
              }   
              })

            }
        })
  }

}
```

and this is my providers

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AngularFire,FirebaseAuth,FirebaseRef} from 'angularfire2';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import * as querybase from 'querybase';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Network } from 'ionic-native';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var Connection;


@Injectable()
export class Authservice {

 users=[];
 complaints=[];
 neighbours=[];
  constructor(public af:AngularFire,public auth:FirebaseAuth) {
    console.log('Hello Authservice Provider');
  }

  //getcurrentuser

  getcurrentuser()
  {

    return this.auth.subscribe(data=>{
      //console.log(data);
    });

  }

  //get all user

  getalluser()
  {
    return this.af.database.list('/users',{preserveSnapshot:true});
  }

  //currentUserID

  getcurrentuserID()
  {

    var email=localStorage.getItem('email');
   return this.af.database.list('/users',{query: {
    orderByChild: 'EMAIL',
    equalTo: email,
    }});
 }



  //Get Emergency

  GetEmergencytype(id)
  {
    var val1=id.toString();
     return this.af.database.list('/alarm',{query: {
    orderByChild: 'APART_ID',
    equalTo: val1
    }});
  }


}
```

I called this function in constructor.It's work properly at first time.again goto page2 after click page1.this function called many times.

I mean consoled the value of this.EMERGENCY many times.

any other user push firebase collections.I need get updated value only.

How i am able to do this.

Kindly help me,

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code for page navigation also? page1 --> 2 and vise versa..

Comment: Thanks.Actually i used sidemenu in my app.i used this way this.nav1.setRoot(page.component);

Comment: can you please provide more details(code) about your pages? put all on your original post.please don't put that on a comment section.

Comment: @ Sampath I update my all code.Kindly help me..

Comment: @ Sampath can u help me...

Comment: can you tell me what did you mean by `page1` and `page2`? I cannot see that components in your code above? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Sampath .I opened my app.login in user goto rootpage(dashboardpae).user goto another page(MycomplaintPage) or anyother pages.and again goto dashboardPage.consoled the value of this.EMERGENCY. Its consoled many times.I debbug my code.repeated this backround notification functions.How can i fix this pblm?

Comment: @Sampath.Are u there.any other way to fix this pblm...?

Comment: I think this is due to you're using side menu.The behavior of side menu is very different than normal page component. So as a test where can you move side menu content into page component?

Comment: @Sampath.I tried to another way.Backround notifications function defined in app.component.ts.and called this function constructor.Its does not consoled.why?at the same time.I closed my app.again opened consoled the value.